# Using djcelerymon in pylons app

Tags: django, pylons, celery

I am trying to use django-celery monitor in my Pylons app. It says here http://ask.github.com/celery/userguide/monitoring.html#monitoring-nodjango that one can use djcelerymon in a non-Django app.

I did all the steps - that is easy_install django-celery- which completed successfully. But I am unable to start djcelerymon. It gives an exception trace that ImportError: No module named django.core. Does that mean that I have to install django components to use djcelerymon.

If yes, then how do I install t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install django also easy_install django orpip install django. So it could import django.core